# Python equivalent of this matlab function

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, physics, computational-geometry

I am looking for the Python equivalent of this Matlab code:

```
% create a set of 2D points
points = [0 0; 1 0; 1 1; 0 1; 0.5 0.5];

% compute the Delaunay triangulation
tri = delaunay(points);

% plot the points and the triangles
triplot(tri, points(:,1), points(:,2));
```

The output is:

[image]

I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import numpy as np

# create a set of 2D points
points = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0.5, 0.5]])

# compute the Delaunay triangulation
tri = Delaunay(points)
# tri = delaunay(points)
trisimp = tri.simplices
# plot the points and the triangles
plt.triplot(points[:,0], points[:,1], tri.simplices)
plt.plot(points[:,0], points[:,1], 'o')
plt.show()
```

[image]
But the result is not the same. I really need the result to be exactly the same because I am migrating a big computational physics project and any discrepancy accrues on my A matrix and I can't validate my migration.

I am open to using any library, it doesn't have to be `scipy` . I looked at the documentation of Matlab and tried:

`tri = Delaunay(points,qhull_options='Qt Qbb Qc')` but it does not work

[image]

Comment: I think they're using different libraries. The matlab version of the function relies on CGAL while the scipy version relies on Qhull.

Comment: I'm sure that the resulting triangulations are equivalent. Your test input is ambiguous, it can be divided into triangles, satisfying the Delaunay constraints, in multiple ways. Is your input in practice likely to be ambiguous like this?